# Flask website can't insert or update into certain tables on AWS EC2 MySQL server

Tags: python, sql, mysql, flask

I made a flask app that runs perfectly on a local sql and flask server, and I was able to deploy it using AWS EC2 instance, where i have a MySQL service and nginx running to make it publicly available on nostalggio.com.

The website just has users create profiles, and each user can then create game records which contain information about their accounts on a certain platform (ex. a game record has info like platform, username, dates).
You can visit [this sample profile](https://www.nostalggio.com/user/1) to help explain the concept.

The problem is that not all Database operations are working and it's quite random, refer to the below list:

WORKING:

- selecting DB rows and entries
- updating user details (username,email,password,bio)
- deleting game records completely

NOT WORKING:

- updating a game records info (ex. changing the platform from playstation to xbox)
- adding new game records
- creating new users

There's too many files and snippets to put in the post but here's 1 example of working and 1 example of not working. Note that i'm using mysql.connector

```
#Updating user bio (working) 
        mycursor.execute("UPDATE users SET bio = %s WHERE user_id = %s",(new_bio, user_id))
        mydb.commit()  

#Inserting a new user
     mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (user,email,password) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(user,email,password))
        mydb.commit()   `
```

Again, this works perfectly on a local server, so my assumption is that this has to do with SQL syntax or schema differences between myphpadmin and MySQL, though i'm pretty sure that i've resolved all the differences between them. I also had no issues remotely connecting to the MySQL server.

Please do let me know of any ideas or if you'd like to me to share more code details.

I've tried to check logs for any errors but it doesn't really show me any, so i'm completely lost.

Comment: There is no way anybody could have helped you with this question as you have not provided any error messages that would have given us any hints as to what had gone wrong. Does not work is not a proper error description.

Comment: Yea the thing was that I wasn't getting any error messages, as I mentioned in my answer the issue turned out to be with the database default values so technically there were no "errors" coming up, and as I said there were too many files and details that I couldn't provide them all in the post. Either way thanks for the feedback and I'll try to write better questions in the future. @Shadow

Comment: I'm pretty sure the execute() calls threw mysql errors, you just did not monitor those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue turned out to be because of the "default values" on certain types in MySQL.

There were some differences between the server I was running locally and the cloud server which ended up causing issues when the Flask app was trying to create or update records with optional columns, for example an optional column should have an empty string by default, but instead it was being taken as null.